# How do you use multiple delimiters within a Java scanner?

Tags: java, regex

I have the following string: [4][SSN:4][Name:4][Salary:2][Married:3][98]

I am attempting to use a scanner to obtain each token one at a time and ultimately print the following to the console:

- 4 attributes
- Attribute 1: SSN, String
- Attribute 2: Name, String
- Attribute 3: Salary, double
- Attribute 4: Married, boolean
- 98 records

(Where 4 corresponds to String. 2 corresponds to double, and 3 corresponds to boolean)

The part that I'm having trouble with is setting the scanner to the correct delimiter so that I can receive whats inside each bracket. One at a time, I'm trying to receive "4", "SSN", "4", "Name", etc.
My code currently looks like this: `

```
Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(input);
inputScanner.useDelimiter("\\[\\|\\]\\|:");
int numAttributes = inputScanner.nextInt(); 
System.out.println(numAttributes + " attributes");
for (int i = 0; i < numAttributes; i++ ) {  //Print each attribute 
    String attr_name = scanner.next();
    int attr_type = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Attribute "+i+attr_name+", "+getInputType(attr_type));
}
System.out.println(inputScanner.nextInt() + " records"); 
inputScanner.close();

(Variable "Input" = the string [4][SSN:4][Name:4][Salary:2][Married:3][98])
```

I'm using the assumption that the string will always be formatted correctly.

Comment: Why do you need to use a scanner?  I'd read a line and then parse it.  For the parsing, a regular expression seems like it'd be easy enough.

Comment: And if your are going to use scanners, it might be easier to use a second `Scanner` to parse the components from the first `Scanner`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give `Scanner` a *regex*, and `Scanner` will treat any string that matches the regex as the delimiter. Currently, you have given it this regex:

```
\[\|\]\|:
```

which matches the string "[|]|:" literally, so the scanner will use "[|]|:" as the delimiter. Unfortunately, that's not what you want. You want the scanner to use all these delimiters:

- `[` (at the start of the string)
- `][` (between attributes)
- `:` (between the name and the number)
- `]` (at the end of the string)

So we need a regex that matches all of those. One such regex is:

```
[\[\]:]{1,2}
```

Note that this is more allowing than we need. It matches 1 or 2 characters that are either `[`, `]` or `:`.

In Java:

```
Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner("[4][SSN:4][Name:4][Salary:2][Married:3][98]");

inputScanner.useDelimiter("[\\[\\]:]{1,2}");

int numAttributes = inputScanner.nextInt(); //Receive the first int indicating the number of attributes

System.out.println(numAttributes + " attributes");


for (int i = 0; i < numAttributes; i++ ) {  //Print each attribute
  String attr_name = inputScanner.next();
  int attr_type = inputScanner.nextInt();
  System.out.println("Attribute " + i + " " + attr_name);
}

System.out.println(inputScanner.nextInt() + " records");
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am attempting to use a scanner

Don't. It's the wrong tool for the job.

You can use regex, or just a simple `indexOf()` implementation.

You could do something like this to get started:

```java
String input = "[4][SSN:4][Name:4][Salary:2][Married:3][98]";

List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<>();
for (int start = 0, end; start < input.length(); start = end + 1) {
    if (input.charAt(start) != '[')
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("At index " + start +
                ": Expected '[', found '" + input.charAt(start) + "'");
    if ((end = input.indexOf(']', start)) == -1)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected end of input: Missing ']'");
    tokens.add(input.substring(start + 1, end));
}
tokens.forEach(System.out::println);
```

*Output*

```
4
SSN:4
Name:4
Salary:2
Married:3
98
```